# Поиск элемента класса в векторе по данным члена

Tags: c++

Допустим, у меня есть такой класс:

```
class Client{
private:
    string name; // имя водителя
    string marka; // марка машины
    string nomer; // номер машины
}
```

и вектор:

```
vector <Client> client;
```

Как мне найти индекс, марку машины и её номер по имени водителя?

Comment: Перебором. Особенно учитывая, что для одного имени водителя может быть несколько машин...

Comment: не очень понимаю как это всё реализовать

Comment: В классе ```Client``` должна быть либо функция, возвращающая имя, и тогда Вы должны пройти по всему вектору, для каждого объекта получить имя и сравнить с искомым, либо функция, получающая на вход строку, и возвращающая результат ее сравнения с именем. Аналогично, проходим по вектору, вызываем для каждого объекта эту функцию. Там, где получили ```true``` - искомый автомобиль (или один из них. если имена не уникальны)

Comment: спасибо, наконец-то дошло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

где то так

```
std::string name = "wesbi";
auto it = std::find_if(client.begin(), client.end(), [name](const Client& c) {return c.name == name;}
if (it == client.end()) {
  // нет данных
} else {
  std::cout << "номер " << it->nomer << "\n"
}
```

пользуемся стандартным алгоримом и лямбдой.